# Integer or double return value

Tags: java, casting

I have an Integer value been passed in and then it is divided by 100, so result could either be an int or double so not sure if cast it or not.

```
public void setWavelength(Integer value) {
    this.wavelength = value;
}
```

then value divided by 100

```
pluggable.setWavelength(entry.getPluggableInvWavelength()/100);
```

So not sure how to cast this value/object

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `Integer` instead of `int`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if entry.getPluggableInvWavelength() returnsd an `int` the results of `/100` will also be an `int`

If you have to have a double result, then you must store a double result.

```
double wavelength;

public void setWavelength(double value) {
    this.wavelength = value;
}  

pluggable.setWavelength(entry.getPluggableInvWavelength()/100.0);
```

Dividing by 100.0 is all you need to have a double result with 2 decimal places.

Comment: Sorry entry.getPluggableInvWavelength() returns an int, I'm have to display result in nanometers. So result may be 85000/100=850nms or say 13455/100=134.55. So should I cast entry.getPluggableInvWavelength() as '((double) entry.getPluggableInvWavelength()) /100)'

Answer (score 4):

If you divide an integer (`int`) by an other integer (`int`) the result will be an integer (`int`) again.
-- More details: [15.17 Multiplicative Operators](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#239829)

You need to mark one or both as double

```
//cast the divisor entry.getPluggableInvWavelength() to double
pluggable.setWavelength( ((double) entry.getPluggableInvWavelength()) /100);
```

or

```
//make the constant quotient a double
pluggable.setWavelength(entry.getPluggableInvWavelength() /100.0);
```

---

Pay attention to the fact, that `java.lang.Integer` is a immutable wrapper type and not an `int`! - In fact you can not calculate with `java.lang.Integer`, but since Java 1.5 the compiler will convert `int` to `Integer` and back automatically (auto boxing and auto unboxing). But in general it is better to understand the difference and use `Integer` only if you real need objects (and not numbers to calculate).

Answer (score 2):

If `waveLength` is `double`, then have:

```
entry.getPluggableWavelength() / 100d;
```

`d` means that the number is treated as `double`, and hence the division result is `double`.

Comment: in fact you can just write: `entry.getPluggableWavelength() / 100.0;` 100.0 will be considered double and the result will be a double.

Answer (score 1):

If you divide an `int` by an `int`, you always get an `int`.  If you want a `float` or a `double` (because you need to represent fractional parts of the result), then you'll need to cast one or both inputs:

```
int a = 3;
int b = 4;

int    c1 = a / b;                  // Equals 0
double c2 = a / b;                  // Still equals 0
double c3 = (double)a / (double)b;  // Equals 0.75
```